# Linked List: Segmentation fault error when assigning a value to the next part of a node

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

This is my first question here and my English is not very good, so please bear with me.

I trying to create a linked list with a function to insert an element in a certain position. To do this I need to position PREDPTR but I am having trouble doing it because whenever I run the program, I always get a segmentation fault. I believe the error is in "predptr->next = first;" part inside the insert() function, but when I set predptr (the line above) to "predptr = new Node()" it works but it always triggers the second case in the insert function.

Here's the code:

```
//Class List
class List
{
private:

  //Class Node
  class Node
  {
  public:

    string data;
    Node * next;

    //Node constructor
    Node()
    {
      data = "";
      next = 0;
    }

    //Node constructor with value
    Node(string val)
    {
      data = val;
      next = 0;
    }
  };

  int mySize;
  Node * first;

public:

  //List constructor
  List()
  {
    mySize = 0;
    first = 0;
  }
//Insert Function
  void insert(string val, int pos)
  {
    Node * newptr, * predptr;
    newptr = new Node(val);
    predptr = new Node();
    predptr->next = first;

    cout << "Pred: " << newptr->data << endl;

    //Position predptr
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
      predptr = predptr->next;

    //CASE 1: Inserting at the middle or end of the List
    if(predptr != 0)
    {
      cout << "NF" << endl;
      newptr->next = predptr->next;
      predptr->next = newptr;
    }
    //CASE 2: Inserting at the beginning of the List
    else
    {
      cout << "F"  << endl;
      newptr->next = first;
      first = newptr;
    }

    delete predptr;
    mySize++;

  }
int main()
{
  List a;
  cout << (a.empty() ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
  cout << "Inserting 5 elements..." << endl;
  a.insert("Asus", 1);
  a.insert("Acer", 2);
  a.insert("Sony", 3);
  a.insert("Toshiba", 4);
  cout << "List A: ";
  a.display();
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The methods `empty` and `display` are missing. When lines which call these methods are commented out, everything works ok. So, probably there's something wrong in one of these methods. With no code it's impossible to find the bug

Comment: predptr = predptr->next; what if you pass a pos and predptr->next is not valid? - pos is not tied to the list in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first clue that something might be wrong would be here, in `insert()`:

```
newptr = new Node(val);
predptr = new Node();
```

Rules of logic dictate that if `insert()` is expected to add one value to the list, then creating two new nodes, instead of one, would obviously be wrong. You expect to create only one new node, here. Not two.

The logic in `insert()` is completely wrong. Can't really do much to salvage it. The only option here is to rewrite it from scratch:

```
Node * newptr=new Node(val);

Node **predptr=&first;

while ( (*predptr) && pos)
{
    predptr= & (*predptr)->next;
    --pos;
}

newptr->next= *predptr;
*predptr=newptr;
```

That's it. If `pos` was passed in as 0, this will insert the new node into the first position in the list, if 1 then second, etc... Things of this nature are 0-based. If you want position #1 instead of position #0 to be the first element of the list, just decrement `pos` before the loop.

If `pos` exceeds the size of the list, the code won't crash, unlike your attempt, but just add the new node to the end of the list.

I'll close this with a quote:

> "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the
>   drain."
>
> Scotty, Star Trek III.

Insertion into a linked list is a simple operation. It should not be a complicated process.

Comment: Hi Sam Varshavchik! Sorry for the VERY LATE reply.It is correct but our professor didn't explain the instructions thoroughly. He was expecting us to use the algorithm and codes found in the book so he did not accept my revised work (according to your answer). But still thank you for answer.

Comment: You need to find a different instructor. Your instructor is incompetent, and is doing more harm than good. If you expect to have a career as a computer programmer, you will not learn much from him.